# How to refactor this multi-table delete statement

Tags: mysql, sql, using, cascade, sql-delete

Can anyone suggest a cleaner method to delete rows with a one-to-many relationship in one query?

This works, but I'm not very familiar with the `using` clause or `delete`, so I don't fully understand how it works.

```
DELETE FROM ip_record,
            entry using ip_record 
            inner join entry 
      where ip_record.site_id = ? 
        and ip_record.ip = ? 
        and ip_record.id = entry.ip_id
```

I have a notion that this could be done more cleanly with a cascade, but I have an irrational fear of constraints. The DB is MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, add the constraint as follows

```
ALTER TABLE entry
    ADD CONSTRAINT constr_entry_fk_ip
    FOREIGN KEY fk_ip (ip_id) REFERENCES ip_record (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

and then you can just use

```
DELETE FROM ip_record
WHERE ip_record.site_id=? and ip_record.ip=?
```

to do what previously required a join.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your walking me through that!